# Fastest way to add column to dataframe containing boolen

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

If I have a pandas dataframe A that looks like:

```
index id some_number some_other_number
1    42       1.2        32
2    54       1.3        33
3    66       3.4        64
4    77       4.7        12
```

and another, dfB, with this:

```
index id some_number some_other_number
1     42     1.2       32
2     99     1.3       33
3     11     3.4       64
4     77     4.7       12
```

What is the fastest way to update dfA such that if the id in the id column is present in dfB we get:

```
index id some_number some_other_number  id_is_in_dfB
1    42       1.2        32               True
2    54       1.3        33               False
3    66       3.4        64               False
4    77       4.7        12               True
```

At the moment i do:

```
dfA["id_is_in_dfB"]=dfA["id"].isin(dfB["id"])
```

I was wondering if there are alternative quicker approaches?

Comment: Are those tables always identical in terms of index-id correspondence as in the example?

Comment: No @dankal444 - there wont be any index-id correspondence necessarily. That is just my small example.

Answer (score 0):

It *might* be faster to do this operation outside of pandas, something like this:

```
prepared_set = set(dfB("id"))
dfA["id_is_in_dfB"]  = [value in prepared_set for value in dfA["id"].values]
```

Can't confirm that in your exact case it will be faster, because it may depend on tables size.

Further improvement might be using `numba`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this approach:

```
dfB['id_is_in_dfB'] = dfA['id']==dfB['id']
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).